# Why isn't [\\s*] equivalent to \\s*?

Tags: java, regex

I'm just getting into regex in Java, I'm reading a book and the Java docs - and I can't figure why - given the following program - that `"[\\s*]"` is not equivalent to `"\\s*"` when used as a delimiter. It seems `"[\\s*]"` is equivalent to `"\\s+"`, can someone walk me through logically why this is so?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class ScanString {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "Smith , where Jones had had 'had', had had 'had had'.";
        String regex = "had";
        System.out.println("String is:\n" + str + "\nToken sought is " + regex);

        Pattern had = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Scanner strScan = new Scanner(str);
        strScan.useDelimiter("\\s*");
        int hadCount = 0;
        while(strScan.hasNext()) {
            if(strScan.hasNext(had)) {
                ++hadCount;
                System.out.println("Token found!: " + strScan.next(had));

            } else {
                System.out.println("Token is    : " + strScan.next());
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Count is: " + hadCount);
    }
}
```

The output, which makes sense to me, is every non-whitespace character as a separate token. When the delimiter is changed to `"\\s+"` or `"[\\s*]"` , the output is:

`String is:
Smith , where Jones had had 'had', had had 'had had'.
Token sought is had
Token is    : Smith
Token is    : ,
Token is    : where
Token is    : Jones
Token found!: had
Token found!: had
Token is    : 'had',
Token found!: had
Token found!: had
Token is    : 'had
Token is    : had'.
Count is: 4`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Brackets `[]` enclose a character class. Inside them, rules about special characters are different. The only special characters there are "the closing bracket (`]`), the backslash (`\`), the caret (`^`) and the hyphen (`-`)." (taken from [this page](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html))

So in this case `[\\s*]` means "either a space or `*`".

When you are dealing with regular expressions, you can use websites like [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) (to test your code) or [Regexper](http://www.regexper.com/) (to visualize graphically the regexp).

Comment: Interesting - the author of my book was misleading! He used the * inside the brackets intended as a special character, but the example worked anyway

Comment: @svenoaks - yea.  Using `[*]` is a bit unconventional.  But it is functionally equivalent to `\*` which needs to be written as `\\*` in a Java String literal.  You could argue that the bracketed version is more readable.

Answer (score 1):

`[]` is [characters class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Take a look at these example: `[abc]` means `a|b|c`. If you create something like `[a*]` it will mean `a|\\*` (`a` or `*` character).